# Editing tag wikis with spam - can that be flagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, flags, spam

There's a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4006632/experience-north-east?tab=activity) editing tag wikis with spam:

- [Simulation tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5693269)
- [Simulation tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5693270)

Is there any way to flag those for moderator attention?

Comment: Let's hope the reviewers keep rejecting those edits...

Comment: I am pretty sure that the system already takes care of this. Too many rejections, and a temp ban. Keep at it... permaban.

Comment: Apparently the user is also spamming in the WordPress site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18802/link-submission-website-ala-reddit/160144#160144

Comment: In situations where there's nothing you can attach a flag to, simply flag any random post with an "other" flag and explain the situation.

Comment: Can "an anonymous user" be banned? Or is that a sign that they are already banned?

Comment: @Michael - Already banned